# Adding UIEliments at runtime, without overlapping

Tags: c#, xaml, overlap, uielement

I am adding an unknown amount of images to a canvas at runtime via code behind but I suspect they are laying on top of each other so only 1 image is visible.

I am converting multiple page PDF's into jpg images with ghostscript and wish to add them to a canvas in a vertical sequential row inside a scroll viewer.

Currently I am just rolling through a for loop generating each jpg and adding it to the canvas with canvas.children.add()

Is there a common way to ensure elements added to a canvas do not overlap? Or a common method people use to make sure children.add places the element in the right position?

I am thinking inside my for loop I will need to see what else exists on the canvas and add the heights together and palace my new image at the correct position but I am not sure how this is done. Is anyone able to steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to add code in my question but I couldn't get the 'add code here' thing to recognize my code so half was in a code box and half wasn't and it looked very untidy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `StackPanel` instead of the `Canvas` and add the images in there. The `StackPanel` will then place the images next to each other (or one under another, depending on its `Orientation`).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I have a few issues to iron out after changing type to stackpanel but I am on my way again. Thanks ChrFin. :)